# Error while hosting a html file on github

Tags: html

although I uploaded html file in the repository, it shows only 'rural' what did I do wrong?[enter image description here](https://i.stack)

[image].imgur.com/3KSMV.jpg

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is perhaps the content of your README.md file.

You need to upload an “index.html” to the root of your repository.

You can also modify the content of the README.md file.

Answer (score 1):

I had once a pretty similar issue so please try this:

1. Go to settings for your repository: You can find Settings tab in
   your repo page.
2. Scroll down to GitHub Pages section on the settings page.
3. In the panel, you will have a Source info that states : '*Your GitHub
   Pages site is currently being built from the gh-pages branch*'.
4. However, in my cases, all code was in master branch. So I selected
   the branch from dropdown as master and in merely a minute, it was
   published successfully.

If it won't solve your issue or you already had this set to master branch - maybe try to commit again so it would refresh